# Can't figure out the "simple" Eclipse rules for command-line arguments for Debug Configurations

Tags: eclipse, bash, debugging, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to debug a program in Eclipse so that the command-line arguments will correspond to the following invocation from the shell

```
[joeuser@host]$ myapp "foo<bar>" -v
```

Now, specifying the arguments as

```
-v "foo<bar>"
```

in the Eclipse Debug Configuration dialog does *not* work - there's a bash message on the console saying:

```
/bin/bash: bar: No such file or directory
```

i.e. the quotation marks get eaten away. I've tried:

- escaping the angle-brackets with backslash
- escaping the angle-brackets with double-backslashes
- escaping the double-quotation marks
- using single quotation marks

and probably some other options - none worked. Now, supposedly, there are "simple rules" on how this is to be done, being one of the answers to this question:

[Eclipse & quotes in command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13594581/1593077)

but that doesn't seem very simple to me, or perhaps I am simpler than those rules. Why can't it just build a string with the command and all of the arguments, unescaped and unsanitized, and just let bash do whatever it does always? :-(

PS - I'm using Eclipse CDT 8.8.1 (Mars.2) on Debian Stretch.

Comment: Where exactly are you specifying this? Putting the value in the 'Program Arguments' section on the 'Arguments' tab of the configuration works fine for me.

Comment: @greg-449: Exactly there...

Comment: This might be of help: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).