# Eclipse launcher mis-parses final command line argument ending in backslash (\)?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-arguments

I have a command line Java program which I launch and run within Eclipse. When I configure the command line arguments, I noticed that it is difficult to express the arguments if the last letter of the last argument is a backslash (`\`). Is this a known bug, or is there a reasonable workaround?

---

Test code:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    }   
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Test cases:

```
Format: String entered into the "program arguments" box
        -->  String printed by Arrays.toString()

C:\      -->  [C:]
C:\ D:\  -->  [C:\, D:]
C:\\     -->  [C:]
C:\\\    -->  [C:]
"C:\"    -->  [C:"]
"C:\\"   -->  [C:\]     (this seems to work, but why?)
'C:\'    -->  ['C:\']
```

Environment:

- Eclipse Mars and EPP Java Package 4.5.1.20150917-1200
- Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45 64-bit, Windows 8.1.

Comment: Huh. Can reproduce with Eclipse Mars.2. That's kinda weird :).

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594581/eclipse-quotes-in-command-line-arguments/34101846#34101846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems using quotation marks and double quotes is the cleanest solution at the moment.

```
"C:\\"

C:\ "D:\\"

C:\ D:\ "E:\\"
```

Answer (score -1):

The last backslash seems to get removed.

A workaround is then `C:\ D:\ \`

Comment: What if this workaround breaks in the next version of Eclipse? This is why I prefer to understand *why* this behavior is happening

Comment: @Nayuki then create an eclipse bug report